# How can I pass an API key to an AngularDart build?

Tags: firebase, angular-dart

What is the best way to pass parameters to AngularDart build so that we can switch to a production api key when done building? We want to point our Firebase to a different client when we build for production.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/73

I use a build script that copies a file before running `pub run build_runner build` or `webdev build`

```
cp web/config_prod.dart web/config.dart
pub run build_runner build web:build --release
cp web/config_dev.dart web/config.dart
```

and import `web/config.dart` in `web/main.dart` (could also be in `lib/` 
and import it from wherever you need to access the values defined in it).

You might also want to follow https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/73 and https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/1053